# Multiple bootstrap tabs - vertical & horizontal

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In an AngularJS+Bootstrap project, I'm trying to create a vertical nav menu/tabs on the left, while the content of one of the tabs should have its own tabs (secondary tabs), horizontal.

My problems:
1. The secondary tabs' contents are displayed outside the desired location
2. Navigation in the secondary tabs doesn't work.

You can check out my code here: http://www.bootply.com/vhArvv1N5V

The main nav bar (vertical) works fine (as demonstrated at: http://www.bootply.com/74926)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the first problem you need to float that first navigation left.  I resolved this by using Bootstrap's `col-md-2` and `col-md-10` around the navigation and the tab content, plus the obligatory row and container-fluid for layout.  To solve the second problem, you missed out some of the `data-toggle="tab"` and `.tab-pane` on the second set of tabs.

I also changed your first nav from `.nav-tabs` to just `.nav`.  Nav tabs rounds the corners etc, not really needed here.  Plus I removed almost all of your CSS and relied more on Bootstrap.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Nav left -->
    <ul class="nav col-md-2" id="leftTabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#a_tab" data-toggle="tab">
          <span></span>ItemA
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#b_tab" data-toggle="tab">
          <span></span>ItemB
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#c_tab" data-toggle="tab">
          <span></span>ItemC - TABS!
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Nav content -->
    <div class="tab-content col-md-10">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="a_tab">
        <h1>Content of A</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="b_tab">
        <h1>Content of B</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="c_tab">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
          <li><a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
          <li><a href="#third" data-toggle="tab">Third</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Nav tabs content -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="first" class="tab-pane active">Content of first</div>
          <div id="second" class="tab-pane">Content of second</div>
          <div id="third" class="tab-pane">Content of third</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/nYAM6ULRUc)**